# Ionic + HammerJS - Scroll left right using pan

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hammer.js

I have an ionic app with a canvas (inside ion-content) and it is wider than screen, so I am using HammerJS to scroll on touch pan.
For scroll to the right (drag screen to the left) it is working:

```
hammer.on('panleft', (ev) => {
  this.content.scrollToPoint(ev.distance, null, 0);
}
```

But the panright is not working well, when drag the screen to the right the scroll jumps to the left, it is not scrolling (smooth as the oposite).

```
hammer.on('panright', (ev) => {
  this.content.scrollToPoint(ev.distance - ev.srcEvent.offsetX, null, 0);
}
```

Tried other examples but with no success...